# why is my code given me this expected [Array(9)] to deeply equall [Array(11)] error

Tags: javascript

am trying to write a code that Given two numbers X and Y, write a function that:
1 returns even numbers between X and Y, if X is greater than Y else it returns odd numbers between x and y, have used every combination i know to test they work but its still given me expected [Array(9)] to deeply equall [Array(11)] error

```js
const number_game = (x, y) => {
  let numArray = [];

  if (x > y) {
    for (i = y + 1; i < x; i++) {
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        numArray.push(i);
      }
    }
    return numArray;
  } else if (x > 1) {
    for (i = x; i < y; i++) {
      if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        numArray.push(i);
      }
    }
    return numArray;
  } else if (x < y || x === y) {
    for (i = x + 2; i < y; i++) {
      if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        numArray.push(i);
      }
    }
    return numArray;
  }
};

console.log(number_game(12, 0));
console.log(number_game(0, 12));
```

Comment: No one will able to help if you dont post the code

Comment: why is **my code** given me...  Which code ?! ?! ?! ?!

Comment: sorry for not including the code at first i have done that now

Comment: Just give us an example input of x and y and then an example output you want and also what your are getting instead. will be much easier to understand the problem

Comment: ok  x=12, y=0 will return [2,4,6,8,10]

Comment: if x = 0 and y = 12 it will return [3,5,7,9,11]

Comment: And what do you expect instead?

Comment: Why would `x=0, y=12` result not include 1?

Comment: The result  is what I want  it to be what I don't  understand  is the error expected [Array(9)] to deeply equall [Array(11)] error

Comment: As for the result not including 1 that was the parameters  i was given not to include one

Comment: The error message you're getting doesn't look like a JavaScript error, it looks like something from the online judge.

Comment: Why do you treat `x > 1` differently from `(x < y || x === y)`? BTW, you can write the last as `(x <= y)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `x > 1` case you're starting from `i`, but the specification says that you're only supposed to return numbers *between* `X` and `Y`, not including them.

And in the `x < y || x == y` case, you're starting from `x+2`. If `x+1` is an odd number, you're not including it. I think you must have misunderstood the problem statement if you think `x = 0, y = 12` should skip `1`.

There's no reason to treat these cases differently. And the case where `x == y` should just return an empty array, it's the special case.

```js
const number_game = (x, y) => {
  let numArray = [];

  if (x > y) {
    for (i = y + 1; i < x; i++) {
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        numArray.push(i);
      }
    }
  } else if (x < y) {
    for (i = x + 1; i < y; i++) {
      if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        numArray.push(i);
      }
    }
  }
  return numArray;
};

console.log(number_game(12, 0));
console.log(number_game(0, 12));
```